# How to get the queued jobs in Quartz Scheduler?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Let's say I've put the threadcount to 2 and I triggered 4 jobs at a time. Then only 2 of them will be executing in the scheduler and rest 2 will be placed in the queue. Is there a direct/indirect method in quartz scheduler using which I can get the queued jobs?

getCurrentlyExecutingJobs() method only gives the jobs that are in process not the queued ones and looping through the getJobGroupNames() I can get all the configured jobs whether completed or running or queued. I need only the queued ones. There is also an approach that I used is to create a different data structure to store the jobs triggered but I would like to know any other approach.